# Separately annotate parts of a fraction

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, equations

I'm trying to create the following image in TikZ as part of a handout explaining blood pressure to patients in a clinic.

I am unsure how to annotate a fraction in tikz. I know of the example [using Beamer arrows to explain terms](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/). The [example for Carl's students](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tutorial/) doesn't apply because it only colors parts of the terms of the equation.

[image]

I've come to TikZ after using a simple array (code below), which won't look as nice.

```
$\begin{array}{cc}
  \underline{120} & \textrm{La cifra superior mide la fuerza de la sangre cuando se contrae el corazon}\\
  80 & \textrm{La cifra inferior mide la fuerza de la sangre cuando el corazon       relaje}
   \end{array}$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth']
  \node[font=\Large] (alta) {120}; 
  \node[font=\Large, below = 3mm of alta] (baja) {80};
  \draw[thick, <-] (alta) --++(30:1cm) node[right, text width=5cm, align=left]{La cifra superior mide la fuerza de la sangre cuando se contrae el corazón};
  \draw[thick, <-] (baja) --++(-30:1cm) node[right, text width=5cm, align=left]{La cifra inferior mide la fuerza de la sangre cuando el corazón relaje};
  \draw[thick] ([yshift=-1.5mm]alta.south west) --  ([yshift=-1.5mm]alta.south east);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```